# RecyclerView doesn't refresh after modifying database's row

Tags: java, android, database, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am programming an app for Android. I uploaded it to GitHub: [app](https://github.com/ftibi93/ViewPager_practice)

I have a ViewPager (MainActivity.java) controlling two Fragments. On the first Fragment (`FirstFragment.java`) you can add People (People.java) which appears on the RecyclerView (also on `FirstFragment.java`). When you click one of the list items on the RecyclerView its details (name and id) appear on the second fragment (`SecondFragment.java`). The SecondFragment.java also contains a button you can delete the selected People with.

To store the People objects I used a List of People and managed it with the methods in PeopleLab.java. The program was working fine: I could add/remove People objects to the list and it appeared on the RecyclerView fine.
After that, I decided to replace the List with a database. It only meant creating the database (the 3 files in database folder) and editing the already existing and two new methods in `PeopleLab.java`. The other files remained untouched. 
The database is working as expected (checked it with sqlite3), I can add/remove People like before and the queries work. My only problem is that the changes don't appear on the RecyclerView. But if I close and reopen the app, the changes appear. 
It's like the RecyclerView doesn't care about the database in runtime, only do when the app starts (or closes, not sure).

Do you have any idea what could cause the problem? My only guess is I miss something about how Android apps handle databases.

*P.S.: sorry for my English.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter but you don't provide any new data for that adapter.

In your `FirstFragment` :

```
private void updateUI() {
    PeopleLab peopleLab = PeopleLab.get(getActivity());
    List<People> peoples = peopleLab.getPeople();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new PeopleAdapter(peoples);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        // You actually have to change your dataset
        mAdapter.changeDataSet(peoples);
    }
}
```

And in your `Adapter` :

```
public void changeDataSet(List<People> people) {
    this.mPeoples = people;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This some brutal way to do it though.
It would be better to notify your adapter on insertion / removal calling `notifyItemInserted(int itemPosition)` or `notifyItemRemoved(int itemPosition)`. (And refreshing your dataset, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work automatically.You can either use to notify the adapter the underlying data has been changed so that adapter can fetch and reload the data.It can be done using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Or use can use [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to achieve the same

Comment: I already use notifyDataSetChanged(). It is called in the button's (which adds new row to the database) onClickListener, and I have another button which's only purpose is to call it.